# Cocoa NSString auto control

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, controls, nstextfield

Hello every one and sorry for my bad english 
i develop a coca app with xcode and interface builder with few label and nstextfield, and a post button.
I want to control dynamically my textfield when i tapping my text (color the text if a character is not allowed or control the lenght).
I have found many solution but i dont know where I must implement the code in my cocoa app :( yet I am able to control my nstextfield when I click to the post button, but not during tapping in nstextfield.
I search many hours about that....

Thanks for yout help !

Answer (score 0):

You can control the text color or font size or even if the text field is enabled or not just by setting properties associated with your `NSTextField`.

If you want to change things when tapping in your `NSTextField`, set some class (your window controller maybe?) to conform to the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol and then connect it to the `delegate` property of the `NSTextField` (either via the XIB or programatically, via the `NSTextField` [`setDelegate'](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/setDelegate:) method.

Then, when clicking on the `NSTextField`, you can catch those click events happening via delegate methods like:

[`[control: textShouldBeginEditing:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control:textShouldBeginEditing:) (which gets called when you click on the text field, or if you tab into position, or whenever the text field becomes the next place where text typed into the keyboard will appear).

Does this make sense so far?

There are lots of `NSTextFieldDelegate` examples that you can Google up and questions with answers you can find here, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969285/nstextfield-delegate-notifications-how-to-get-text).